# minlength maxlength form php no effect

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, themes, parsley

I am trying to edit a php form (two different div segments).

#### 1.)

I am trying to add minlength to a single line text field input. Maxlength works, but only because it is part of the underlying theme. (The form is part of a theme).
I can add minlength, but it doesn't have an effect.

#### 2.)

Similarly, **minlength or maxlength** doesn't have an effect on the textarea field (another div, same form). Oddly enough, **data-parsley-required="true"** works, so the text field becomes required. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers
Siegfried

Example 2)

```
<div class="row"> 
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12"> 
<label class="control-label">' . __('Description') . ' <small>' . __('') . '</small><span class="required">*</span></label> <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" maxlength="14" name="description" id="description" type="text" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-error-message="' . __('Please describe yourself') . '">' . $description . '</textarea>
 </div> 
</div>
```

In the code above you can see that I inserted maxlength after class="". Unfortunately, this does not show in the form - I can input unlimited characters.

Comment: Can you show an example of the changes you make as at the moment it's unclear what you change.

Comment: Edit your question and paste that code that you given to the comment box so that others can see what changes you made

Comment: done. scheck above